# How to get values of List from Firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a data from Firebase as a model and in my model, there is a `List<String>` so I can send it to Firebase but can't get it :(

I have a model where an image is List Image;

```
CollectionReference colRef = db.collection("Vehicle");
colRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
     Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(document.getString("title"),
                                   document.getString("city"),
                                   document.get("image"),                                        }
```

This gives an error saying that I'm getting Object "document.get("image")" or String "document.getString("image")" in sted of List

There is no "document.getList("image")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no "document.getList("image")"

You're right, there is no `getList()` method in the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot) class but because it extends [DocumentSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) class, you can use [get(String field)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#get(java.lang.String)) method:

> Returns the value at the field or null if the field doesn't exist.

So if your `image` property is of type array, you can simply get it as `List` using the following line of code:

```
List<String> vehicleList = (List<String>) document.get("image");
```

Now you can create an object of `Vehicle` class by passing `vehicleList` to the constructor.