# for loop is returning empty and nothing is Displaying on click

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[[Firestore Data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeP0R.png)

When I run the program and click the button its meant to select a random index from my array and display the contents. The random number etc is all working its when it reaches the for loop and it retrieves no data from the array

I have been googling this for a while and are only confusing my self trying different things . sorry im very new to java and android studio

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

        txtDisplay = findViewById ( R.id.textViewDisplay );
        int color = cColorWheel.getColor ();
        txtDisplay.setBackgroundColor ( color );
        //=========================================
        Random rn = new Random ();
        int RN = rn.nextInt ( 14 );
        //========================================================
        FactRef.whereArrayContains ( "facts", RN ).get ()
                .addOnSuccessListener ( new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot> () {

                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder ();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Fact note = documentSnapshot.toObject ( Fact.Class );
                            note.setDocumentId ( documentSnapshot.getId () );

                            String documentId = note.getDocumentId ();


                            data.append ( "Id:" ).append ( documentId );
                            for (String tag : note.getTags ()) {
                                data.append ( "\n-" ).append ( tag );
                            }
                            data.append ( "\n\n" );
                        }
                        txtDisplay.setText ( data.toString () );


                    }
                } );
    }
```

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you think should be selected? Also: can you try with a hardcoded value instead of `RN`? I'd recommend trying a number (e.g. `4`) *and* the same number as a string (`"4"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using the following lines of code:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int RN = rn.nextInt(14);
FactRef.whereArrayContains("facts", RN).get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

To return one random item from the `facts` array based on an index that is equal with a number between 0 to 14, please not that this is not possible. There is no way you can query your `RNDFacts` collection using `whereArrayContains()` based on a particular index. That method is searching for an item that is equal to the item it self. For instance, if you want search in the array for:

> Superman Didn't Always Fly

This is the query that you should be using:

```
String fact = "Superman Didn't Always Fly";
FactRef.whereArrayContains("facts", fact).get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

If you want to get a random item from the `facts` array, you should get the entire document, [get the `facts` array property as a `List<String>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57744982/5246885) and use the following lines:

```
List<String> facts = (List<String> facts) document.get(facts);
Random rn = new Random();
int RN = rn.nextInt(facts.size());
String fact = facts.get(RN);
```

Comment: Ok, keep me posted. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: ok i think i have gotten lost on this sorry  - https://imgur.com/2GFmY2r

Comment: `FactRef` should be a `CollectionReference` and **not** a `DocumentReference`. You should remove the call to `document("Facts")`. Does it work this way?

Comment: some reason the List<String> facts in the brackets stays red

Comment: ok not sure how i did it but i have done it and have the code displaying the random fact :)  thank you vewry much for the help as it helped me amazingly  ;)    https://imgur.com/GFV0NcC